# Adding a discount amount to payment request to PAYPAL through REST API

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using PAYPAL Rest API for payment transaction. I am calling context(/v1/payments/payment) for authorization and passing the ItemList as part of Transaction object.

Requirement: To Display Discount/GiftCard amount as part of the ItemList on the Paypal authentication page.

Problem: The API doesn't allow to put negative amount to an item and validation error is thrown.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to display discount/gift card negative amount. (It is possible in Classic API though)

Comment: Can you edit your question, and include the code that is throwing the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Negative amount are supported now.
For example in PHP SDK you can pass -ve values as line item.

```
$item1 = new Item();
$item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice('5.00');
$item2 = new Item();
$item2->setName('Discount')
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice('-2.00');
```

[image]

Comment: Negative amounts are not supported now. It is throwing error message as `Price should be positive number`.

Comment: @Mdumanoj We pass subtotal discounts as a negative line item currently. 
 The docs also suggest otherwise.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

From the notes on L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMTn:

Value is *typically* a positive number that cannot exceed 10,000.00 USD or the per transaction limit for the currency.   Note: If the line item is a discount, a negative value must be passed in this field.